# Python nested for loops with object arrays

Tags: python, arrays, oop, object

So, im creating nodes (2 input and 2 output). And I want to connect those nodes with links. for this I have the class Node and the class Link.

```
class Node:
    all_link_incoming = []
    all_link_outgoing = []

class Link:
    node_incoming = 0.0
    node_outgoing = 0.0
```

I want to connect each Input node with both Output nodes, thus creating a link from input node 1 to output nodes 1 and 2. (see following image)
[nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SK5c3.png)

To create the links that connect these nodes, I use the following piece of code:

```
for node_input in all_node_input:
    for node_output in all_node_output:
        link = Link(node_input, node_output)
        node_input.all_link_outgoing.append(link)
        node_output.all_link_incoming.append(link)
```

However, after both for loops have run once (So input node 1 should be connected to output node 1, nothing else). Output node 2 also contains the (same) created link to input node 1.

So after running this piece of code, each output node should contain 2 links, but they both contain the same 4 links.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks a lot!

(Btw, I added some debug lines to check this, these lines and output looks like:)

```
print(all_node_output[0].all_link_incoming)
print(all_node_output[1].all_link_incoming)

[<__main__.Link object at 0x104704d30>, <__main__.Link object at 0x104704d68>, <__main__.Link object at 0x104704da0>, <__main__.Link object at 0x104704dd8>]
[<__main__.Link object at 0x104704d30>, <__main__.Link object at 0x104704d68>, <__main__.Link object at 0x104704da0>, <__main__.Link object at 0x104704dd8>]
```

Comment: You are only using class variables in your class definition(i.e. they are *shared* across instances)... You should be using instance variables

Comment: Also, these are not arrays, they are `list` objects.

Comment: You are my hero, thanks a lot!